# Pasting links as HTML makes Word slow

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, bookmarks

I have recentely started copying and pasting bookmarks from other documents, but pasting them as a HTML link so that they are inserted as `OLE_LINK1`, `OLE_LINK2`, etc.  This has caused the Word files to become a lot slower.

When I click on one of these bookmarks which points to a section of the current document itself, the status bar keeps flashing "Opening …" messages, and after a dozen of such messages are displayed, then finally the document goes to the place where the bookmark points to.

Why is this happening, and is there a solution for it?

---

Also, some of my Word files are getting huge.  I have some which are 800 pages with lots of figures, and over 32 meg in file size.  Should I be worried about such large files, or can Word handle it?

Comment: Word can handle large file sizes as long as *you* don't run out of memory.

Comment: Are you keeping up on Windows Updates?  They tend to fix a lot of weird issues such as things like this.

Comment: Yes, I keep Windows completely updated. The second question has something to do with those OLE_Link bookmarks.  I can stop using them, but I want to know if they are in general a problem, or they are causing problem only for my document.

Comment: Note that you should only ask **one question at a time**. I edited the first part of your question, as it is quite general and probably has been asked/answered before. Your second question seemed more relevant and practical.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you *should* be worried about such a large file size (for example search this site for ‘large Word file’). It would be a lot of work to lose if it gets corrupted! (the likelihood of which seems greater for large files than for a similar total volume of small files). Remember also that while editing the file size may be significantly larger than after a full save (because of undo history). Also, repaginating very many pages can take a long time (during which further edits may not be accepted).

Occasionally some books have no chapters but very large documents are almost always broken up into ‘sections’ (Preface, Chapters, Appendices etc) and that applies as much to hard copy as to e-format – so presumably for a good reason (that they are simply more convenient that way).

Once more or less ‘finished’ I personally might reassemble the sections into a single file but I’d still keep the components and use only the components while doing any heavy editing. And I would aim for about 5MB max per section (though that would be after compression should that make much difference), in part because I often need to e-mail what I edit.

Per [kb211489](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211489) (applies to Word2007 & Word 2010): *The maximum file size is limited to 32 MB for the total document text only and does not include graphics, regardless of how the graphics image is inserted (Link to file, Save with document, or Wrapping style) into the document. Therefore, if the file contains graphics, the maximum file size can be larger than 32 MB.*

The maximum that can be opened (ibid) is 512MB so in theory you have some headroom but as already over 32MB I'd say you are on dangerous ground. Also, I suspect if broken up into about half a dozen pieces your other problem (speed - or lack of it!) would be ameliorated.